# CloudFlare cuts HTTP POST Content

Tags: c#, .net, http, proxy, http-post

I communicate with a server that is behind CloudFlare. I seldom get an error from the server as if it doesn't receive content of my HTTP POST request. It happens really rarely (maybe 1-2%). Also if I just immediately resend the same request it works fine in most (~99%) cases.

I had no problems with the server when it was not behind CloudFlare or when they used another similar service. Also if the server is moved temporary out of CloudFlare the problem disappears. I have exactly the same problem problem with another server that is also behind CloudFlare.

I'm using C# .NET 4.5. The connection is secured (HTTPS).

I've captured HTTP request/response using Fiddler. I see absolutely no differences between "bad" and "good" requests.

```
POST https://btc-e.com/tapi HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Key: ****************
Sign: e94eb19d4cdf29b6629c2acc6934bacdf502bdc93c14a44521ef9d64823f4ab560ef14fce468b7df897f0b2f2f4677c4191801f7453c784bda7fd0ede4b95f59
Host: btc-e.com
Content-Length: 42

nonce=1362901653&method=OrderList&active=1

======================================================

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Sun, 10 Mar 2013 08:41:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.12
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Expires: Sun, 17 Mar 2013 08:40:56 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=****************; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.btc-e.com
CF-RAY: 4ceb4731fea02d9

10e
{"success":0,"error":"*************"} 0
0
```

I' am using the below code but I do not think it's relevant:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(BuildPostData(args)); //values are properly encoded using HttpUtility.UrlEncode

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(ApiUri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.Timeout = 5000;
request.Headers.Add("Key", Key);
request.Headers.Add("Sign", sign);    

using (Stream outStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    outStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    outStream.Flush();
}

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    result = JObject.Parse(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
```

What I've already tried without any success:

- HTTP 1.1 / 1.0
- KeepAlive on/off
- Expect 100-continue on/off
- Cookies enabled / disabled
- Send chunked on/off

Any ideas please?

UPDATE:
2013-05-01 The problem is gone. No changes on client side. Just gone after 3-4 weeks...